# How can i completely remove or uninstall hidden software

Tags: windows-10, uninstall

I have installed a keylogger software to collect my own details. (to prevent any data loss of my work) Somehow the software doesn't appear when I press the hotkey combination as it supposes to be. so I can't uninstall it because the software is invisible. There is no evidence even it is still in my PC. The software is taken from here. 
http://bestxsoftware.com

please let me know how can I completely uninstall this kind of software.

Comment: Does it show in add remove programs ? Does it have a service/process running ?

Comment: @pun it doesn't show in add remove program list. And I can't identify the process or service by name on the task manager.

Comment: May be you can't unhide it because your virus scanner classified it as potential unwanted software and killed it plus deleted the executable?

Comment: @Robert That could be the reason. I have re-install the setup and now it's working properly. during the installing process, the setup has advised me to ad an exception to the antivirus. ( I have forgotten to do that last time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[FAQ: How to uninstall Best Free Keylogger.](https://bestxsoftware.com/How-to-uninstall.html)

> 1. Unhide Best Free Keylogger. (If you have problems logging into the GUI follow [this instructions](https://bestxsoftware.com/I-cannot-unhide-best-free-keylogger.html))
> 2. Go to 'Settings' > 'General Settings'
> 3. Click Uninstall Now button.

[FAQ: I can’t unhide Best Free Keylogger.](https://bestxsoftware.com/I-cannot-unhide-best-free-keylogger.html)

> Press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> together. (this is the default unhide hotkey. you can change it in Settings > General Settings > Security)
>
> **Alternatively you can unhide this way:**
>
> 1. Press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> keys to launch Run Dialog
> 2. Type "**unhide**" in Run dialog (this is the default unhide keyword. you can change it in Settings > General Settings > Security)
> 3. Do **NOT** press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: thank you for the information. But the best free keylogger unhider exe says: "Cannot find running instance of Best free keylogger. unhiding failed"

Comment: @Razi If so re-install it, then remove completely. Or you may revert to system restore point before this software installation (if exists).

Comment: Re-installing is a good idea. I will try it.